# Get pods in Kubernetes where all containers are "ready" in one line using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We have cluster with Istio and also Jenkins job to get "stable" pods, which uses this `kubectl` query:

```sh
kubectl get po -o=jsonpath="{range .items[?(@.status.containerStatuses[-1].ready==true)]}{.spec.containers[0].image}{'\\n'}{end}"
```

```
registry/my-proj/admin:2.0.0.000123
registry/my-proj/foo:2.0.0.000123
registry/my-proj/bar:2.0.0.000123
```

This query fetches pods where last container (application) is ready, because we also have Istio sidecar containers. But here is tricky thing, it looks like array is built using alphabet, so if Istio container will be last - it fetches it as ready pod, because last container is ready.

I've tried to use `go-template` also, but the best thing I've managed to do

```sh
kubectl get po -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{if eq .ready true }}{{end}}{{end}}{{.metadata.name}}{{println}}{{end}}
```

```
registry/my-proj/admin:2.0.0.000123
registry/my-proj/admin:2.0.0.000123
registry/my-proj/foo:2.0.0.000123
registry/my-proj/foo:2.0.0.000123
registry/my-proj/bar:2.0.0.000123
```

It fetches **2** times pods where 2 containers are ready and only **1** if **1** container is ready.

**TL;DR;**

I am looking for ultimate query which can fetch pods where **all containers are ready**, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get all ready pods:**

```
kubectl get po -o go-template='{{ $readyFlag := true}}{{range .items}}{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{ if not .ready}}{{ $readyFlag = false}}{{end}}{{end}}{{if $readyFlag }}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

**Get all not ready pods:**

```
kubectl get po -o go-template='{{ $readyFlag := true}}{{range .items}}{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{ if not .ready}}{{ $readyFlag = false}}{{end}}{{end}}{{if not $readyFlag }}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

**Implementation details:**

1. We define variable *$readyFlag* with initial value *true*
2. We loop over all containers statuses and if its field ".ready" is not *true* - update our flag value to *false*
3. In the end we just check if *$readyFlag* has value *false* - then at least one of checked containers had status not ready. If value *true* - then all containers was ready

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this?

```
kubectl get po -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{range .items}}{{$pod := .}}{{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{if eq .ready false}}{{$pod.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}' | sort | uniq -u
```

What's happening here:

1. We are getting all existing pod names, delimited by newline
2. Appending all pod names, which have at least one not ready container, delimited by newline
3. Sorting output alphabetically
4. Getting unique lines, while excluding duplicate ones.

The trick is that `-u` key excludes all duplicate entries, so all that is left is running pods.
`{{ $pod := .}}` is used to save outer scope to print pod name inside inner loop. "Get all pods" is coming after "get not ready pods" to reduce risk of possible race condition, when some pods may have become ready by the time we did a "get all pods" query.

I do believe that something like this can easily be achieved with jsonpath too, but I don't think that you'll be able to do it with kubectl only, without the usage of `sort` and `uniq`.

Comment: Thank you, I also thought about that, but I need to grep duplicated lines rather than single ones

Using my example it must result in ->
registry/my-proj/admin:2.0.0.000123
registry/my-proj/foo:2.0.0.000123

Comment: Well, your questions states "I am looking for ultimate query which can fetch pods where all containers are ready", which is answered by my answer. Please update your question if you have other requirements.

Comment: go-template function fetches pod 2 times, it means that 2 containers (all containers) in pod are ready, you are fetching only unique strings (which occur 1 time) in your script. I won't update my question, you just didn't get it right.

Comment: My first template fetches all *pods* only, all of them.  my second  template fetches only pod names, where _at least one_ container is failed. So if pod has 1 Ready container and 1 Not ready - it will print it's name once. If it has 10 containers out of which 9 are not ready - it will print pod name 9 times. `uniq -u` will remove any pod, which is present more than once in output, which happens only if at least one container is not ready. I still don't get why you think that this answer is not correct.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that you have changed function, I thought you've added only `| sort | uniq -u` to mine, yes this will work thank you! Let's give some time to look up for other answers and I will accept yours if it will be the best

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with `grep`, you can use the following command:

```
kubectl get pod |grep -Po '^([^ ]+)(?=\s+((\d+)\/\3))'
```

Example:

```
kubectl get pod
NAME    READY   STATUS     RESTARTS        AGE
bar     2/2     Running    0               5m12s
foo     1/3     NotReady   6               6m9s
mypod   1/1     Running    2 (9m58s ago)   21h

kubectl get pod |grep -Po '^([^ ]+)(?=\s+((\d+)\/\3))'
bar
mypod
ps@controller:~$
```

Comment: Yep, this will work too, thank for you answer, but I'm scared of grep ;D
I prefer more elegant solution, but will +1 your answer too